# sorting takes 2 hours on vagrant - approx 100m lines

Tags: linux, sorting, ubuntu, optimization, vagrant

**What can I do to optimize this sort?**

I am running:

```
mytime="$(time ( cat quotes_2009-04.txt | tr [:space:] '\n' | grep -v "^\s*$" | sort | uniq -c  ) 2>&1 1>/dev/null )"
```

and then:

```
echo "$mytime"
```

getting the following output:

```
real    134m0.107s
user    105m27.274s
sys 42m34.889s
```

here's the datatset that I am using:

[image]

a preview of the original dataset:

[image]

here are the details on the vagrant machine:

[image]

**What can I do to optimize this sort?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split your data into several files, sort each file in parallel, then merge the files together.  see [here](http://arnab.org/blog/quick-and-easy-multicore-sort) for example.